# Android fragment ignores button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

I have a button inside a fragment. If I click on that button nothing happens. I followed several tutorials and basically everyone does the things that I do. In another application that I developed some weeks ago, I did the same thing and it worked... What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for all the tips!

Fragment class

```
package com.geko;

import com.geko.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.Session;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Lev1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lev1, container, false);

    Button button1= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.level1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);   

    return v;        
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Context context = getActivity();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed!",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
}
```

Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/level1"

        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="livello1"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your button on a higher level of access. In your code, the button object got out of scope and is no longer in managed memory.
Sample code:

```
public class Lev1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

Button button1;
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

...
    button1= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.level1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Interesting note: If you use the nested class method like some suggested, then the scope of the button object is not an issue. But I do like your code of using **implements OnClickListener**, it makes the code look cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I still think it's a pretty weird problem, but for now it's solved...

Comment: Good! Sometimes the Java JVM does not work right, not perfect.

Comment: @esseara, If you think my answer is helpful, you may click on the up-arrow icon, on top of the checkmark, also.  Good day...

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using the wrong context.

```
button1.setOnClickListener({
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = getActivity();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
});
```

EDIT: remove also `import com.geko.R;` from the imports!

Comment: None of these work. Context aside, I don't get anything even if I display a message on the log when the button is pressed. It's like it doesn't get the click.

Comment: @esseara Are you totally sure of this? With the code that you put here i don't see why it isn't working..

Comment: I'm sadly sure... I too don't understand where the problem is, I used this method in other applications. It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
Context context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

with

```
Context context = getActivity();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of these workarounds if you don't solve your problem for a Button click.

A)

```
    Button button1= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.level1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

B)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/level1"

    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="yourNewMethod"
    android:text="livello1"
     />
```

then on java

```
public void yourNewMethod(View v){
     //Whatever you need to do
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change a little in your `onClick` method:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.level1:
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pressed!",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is context coming from? The problem is his `Context` is wrong. See @Fondesa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to listen/catch the click event. I suspect that there is a conflict with your event in this project. Make sure the context is the button for the click by referencing **View** or Button (to be specific) like this:

```
public class Lev1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
...

public class Lev1 extends Fragment implements Button.OnClickListener {
...
```

Post your imports in this Java file.

Comment: @esseara, I posted another answer and I think I know the root problem.